# Create Multilanguage QtQuick App with QtLinguist

Tags: qt, multilingual, qtquick2, qt-linguist

I do this stuff for research, so there´s no source code.

My programm has to be able to change the language via buttons. I got the information that the `QtLinguist`is often used for this stuff. The problem is that I can´t find something like a workflow, what and when do I have to do something.

It would be nice if someone can give me a push in the right direction.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-internationalization.html and https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_do_dynamic_translation_in_QML may help you